# Can't write inside text box after creating it whit js

Tags: javascript

hi so i made something like a table i need it for my matrix but after creating the columns i observed that i can't write inside them

```js
function create(param) {

    var i, target = document.getElementById('results');
 var matrix = []
    target.innerHTML = '';

    for(i = 0; i < param; i += 1) {
 target.innerHTML +='<br>'
  for(var j=0;j<param;j+=1)
        target.innerHTML += '<input type="text"id="' + "value_" + i + "_" + j + '">';
    }
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="create(5)" style="width:300px;height:30px;"/><br><br>
<div id="results"> </div>
</body>
</html>
```

What do i have to modify/write/delete to can write inside them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<button>` is not a self closing tag. You need to include `</button>` .  Otherwise, the tag is unclosed until the end of the document. This causes your results div to capture the onclick event that writes the table.  The result is that clicking into your text boxes causes the table to be rewritten.

```js
function create(param) {

    var i, target = document.getElementById('results');
 var matrix = []
    target.innerHTML = '';

    for(i = 0; i < param; i += 1) {
 target.innerHTML +='<br>'
  for(var j=0;j<param;j+=1)
        target.innerHTML += '<input type="text"id="' + "value_" + i + "_" + j + '">';
    }
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="create(5)" style="width:300px;height:30px;"></button><br><br>
<div id="results"> </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @LuisFernandoScripcaru No worries.  That's what this site is for.  Glad I could help. :)

Answer (score 0):

Why?

Function is runned everytime you click an input.
This overwrites the input -> you cant fill it.

This is a hotfix, if you want to run the function "create" more than only one time, the fix doesnt work for you.

Better fix: check always your tags and close them and make sure, that the inputs arent in a HTML-Element, running the create func.

```js
var runnedCreate = false;

function create(param) {

    if (runnedCreate != true ) {
        var i, target = document.getElementById('results');
     var matrix = []
        target.innerHTML = '';

        for(i = 0; i < param; i += 1) {
     target.innerHTML +='<br>'

         for(var j=0;j<param;j+=1) {
                target.innerHTML += '<input type="text"id="' + "value_" + i + "_" + j + '">';
            }
        }
        runnedCreate = true;
   }
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="create(5)" style="width:300px;height:30px;"/><br><br>
<div id="results"> </div>
</body>
</html>
```